# Assign inventory by customer group with MSI?

Tags: magento2.3, inventory, msi, magento2-b2b

We have a site with B2C Customers and B2B customers. The Inventory of each came for different warehouses. So, the requirement is that B2C customer only watches and buy the products in stock on B2C Inventory and B2B Customer only watch and buy products in stock on B2B Inventory.

So, I see with MSI you can create different sources and stocks and assigns products to these. However, I don't see any configuration in production, source, or stock that allows me to restrict the Inventory by customers.

Is there something by default natively in Magento that allows me to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

A stock can be assigned to a website. At the same time, you can redirect a customer depending on a group to a corresponding website. Alternatively, you can create a customer group sales channel to assign stock depending on a customer group or whatever you want similar to how it is implemented for websites. But this feature will require some coding. Also, there is a store view sales channel available on the web.